# How a non async value is wrapped in a Future using await?

Tags: dart

[Docs](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#handling-futures) says:

> In await expression, the value of expression is usually a Future; if it isn’t, then the value is automatically wrapped in a Future.

So, if I use:

```dart
void main() async {
  var a = await 1;
  print(a); // Prints 1
  print(Future.value(1)); // Prints `Instance of _Future<int>`. 
}
```

Using what the docs says, the first print should print `Instance of _Future<int>` but it prints `1`. Can anyone explain what that line means by `the value is automatically wrapped in a Future`?

Comment: @Dude *"In await expression, the value of expression is usually a Future; if it isn’t, then the value is automatically wrapped in a Future."*

Comment: @Dude Does it not mean that `1` is wrapped in Future and if yes, shouldn't it print `Future<int>`?

Comment: It means that `1` is wrapped in a `Future`, so `await 1` is equivalent to `await Future.value(1)`, which then waits for that future to complete and evaluates to `1`.

Comment: @lrn Thanks, would you mind writing it as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of

> In `await` expression, the value of expression is usually a `Future`; if it isn’t, then the value is automatically wrapped in a `Future`.

is that for an expression like `await 1`, where the value of `1` is not a `Future`, the `1` is replaced by `Future.value(1)`. The meaning of `await` can then be defined entirely in terms of what it does to futures, and it's clear that there *will* be an asynchronous delay at the `await`.

The `await 1`, aka. `await Future.value(1)`, waits for the future to complete with the value `1`, then the entire `await 1` expression evaluates to that value. The `await` always removes "one layer of `Future`" from the value by waiting for the future to complete with a value, and then evaluate to to that value.

For `await e`, if `e` *throws*, then `await e` also throws immediately. The error is not wrapped up in a future. Only if `e` evaluates to a value, *and* that value does not implement `Future`, then the value is wrapped so that it can be awaited and unwrapped again.

Answer (score 0):

The `await` causes the function to wait for the `Future` to complete. This example code:

```
waitFunction1() async {
  var x = await 1;
  print(x);
  return x;
}

waitFunction2() async {
  var x = await 2;
  print(x);
  return x;
}

main(List<String> args) async {
  var x = waitFunction1();
  print('1: $x');
  var y = await waitFunction2();
  print('2: $y');
  var z = await x;
  print('1: $z');
}
```

produces the output:

```
1: Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'
1
2
2: 2
1: 1
```

The call to `waitFunction1` returns the `Future`. Later when it waits for it, we get the value wrapped by the `Future`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But `waitFunction1` is already a `Future` but in my question I'm asking how a "non-async" value is wrapped in a `Future`. Maybe I didn't get how your answer answers the post.

Comment: In my example I have the same `await 1` then you had. This wraps the `1` in a `Future` as you see in my output. In your code the `await` keyword causes your async function `main` to block and wait for the result of the `Future`, which is of course `1`. Because you use `await` your function does not see the `Future`, but callers of your function do, as you can see in my output.

Comment: If your function had `var a = Future.value(1)` then `print(a)` would show the `Future`, then after `await a` it would show `1`.

Comment: Even if you don't have `await 1` and a blank body of a function with this signature `Future<int> f() => 1`, it will also print `Instance of Future<int>`, so `await 1` in your code isn't really doing anything.

Comment: Anyways, @lrn has answered the question in comment, thank you for your help :)